# Why Eclipse copies unnecessary files into the bin folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I work on a java project in Eclipse (Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)) and sometimes build an executable jar with ant. In my project folder, I have several working files and directories which are frequently used in my work but are not parts of the project (execution logs, some temp files etc). I need them to be at hand, but I don't need them in the jar. For unknown reason, Eclipse (or, may be, ant?) sometimes copies them into the bin folder, and when I build the jar they get packed into it. I can not figure out the exact moment when these files get copied into the bin folder. In order to keep the jar clean, I have to constantly keep my eyes on the bin folder and delete the unnecessary files manually. I don't like it. Why do Eclipse (or, may be, ant?) behaves this way and how can I prevent this?

Comment: We can't tell you anything about what Ant is doing unless you show us the build.xml.

Comment: You should start by diagnoosing what copies them. Ant builds doesn't just start by itself. If these files are in the sources directory, the Eclipse will copy them. Just don't put them there. The source directory is for sources, not for log files or temp files.

Comment: JB Nizet, greg-449 - thank you for your responses. It was Eclipse. Long ago when I started this project I found it convenient to have all the sources and resources in the project's root folder and had not considered the potential jar building issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse defaults to copying everything from your Source folder(s) to the output (bin) folder.

You can control this in the 'Java Build Path' page of the Project Properties.

Select the 'Source' tab and expand the 'Source folders on build path' entry. You should see 'Included (All)' and 'Excluded (None)' entries. You can edit these to control what is copied.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need! I still don't know **when** it copies the files there  (I see no connection with what I do), but it's not so important.

Comment: It is important. A professional knows what his tools do!

Comment: Eclipse runs incremental builds all the time as you change source code. I guess these check that everything is present in the output folders.

Comment: @greg-449 It seems like the files that has changed after the last execution are copied every time I run the program under Eclipse, no matter have I changed the source or not, and all of the files are copied when the Eclipse performs the full build (e.g. after changing the compiler options).